# Angular 2 - How to send asynchronous information to the template

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular

I'm trying to send to the template some image information after validation. But I'm not getting.

The variables that go to the template are within a callback, or are within an asynchronous function, and I do not know to send this information to the template.

Could help me solve this problem? I've tried everything.

**event.component.ts**

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: '<my-image></my-image>',
    templateUrl: './event.component.html',      
})
export class EventComponent {
    files: File[];
    file: any
    imageName: any;
    imageSize: any;
    whithImage = false;

    ngOnInit() {this.files = []}

    onFileSelect(event) {
        this.files = event.dataTransfer ? event.dataTransfer.files : event.target.files;
        this.file = this.files[0];
        this.isImage(this.file, function(res, file){
            if(res==true){
                this.imageName = file.name;
                this.imageSize = file.size;
                this.whithImage = res;
            }
        }) 
    }

    isImage(file, callback) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var contents = reader.result;
            var buf = new Uint8Array(contents);
            if(buf[0] === 0xFF && buf[1] === 0xD8 && buf[2] === 0xFF){
                callback(true, file) //jpg
            }else{callback(false)}
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    onChooseClick(event, fileInput) {
        fileInput.value = null;
    }
```

**event.component.html**

```
<span (click)="onChooseClick($event, fileinput)">
    Image<input  #fileinput type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event)"/>
</button>
<div *ngIf="whithImage">
    <p>{{ imageName }}</p>
    <p>{{ imageSize }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try what @peeskillet suggested first – i.e., use the proper `this` context by using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```typescript
export class EventComponent {
   onFileSelect(event) {
        ...
        this.isImage(this.file, (res, file) => {     // <----
            if(res==true) {
                this.imageName = file.name;
                this.imageSize = file.size;
                this.whithImage = res;
            }
        }); 
    }
```

If that doesn't work, then Angular not does know how to monkey-patch your asynchronous event, hence when the event fires, Angular change detection doesn't run (so your view doesn't update to reflect the new component property values).  You'll need to [manually trigger change detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually).  Here's one way to do it:

```typescript
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';     // <-----
export class EventComponent {
   constructor(private cdref:ChangeDetectorRef) {}   // <-----
   onFileSelect(event) {
        ...
        this.isImage(this.file, (res, file) => {     // <----
            if(res==true) {
                this.imageName = file.name;
                this.imageSize = file.size;
                this.whithImage = res;
                this.cdref.detectChanges();          //  <------
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Looks more like the problem is the use of `function` and `this` ;-)

Comment: Thank you Mark for his contribution, but even commenting the functions `imageName, imageSize and whithImage` and leaving only  `this.cdref.detectChanges();` the following error appears: `Cannot read property 'cdref' of undefined`

Comment: @MarkRajcok Hi, can you please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49295365/8494729) question?